# Form with FormBorderStyle none, becomes fullscreen when maximized

Tags: vb.net, winforms, fullscreen, formborderstyle

I have a form with `FormBorderStyle` property set to `None` and I have my own panels acting as the title Bar so that my application looks good.

But, the problem is that when the application is maximized, it covers the task bar also, which I don't want.

Any idea why is this happening and what is the solution for it? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behavior with `FormBorderStyle` set to `None`.

To get it the way you want you can set the [`MaximizedBounds`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.maximizedbounds(v=vs.110).aspx)-property of the `Form` to match the [`WorkingArea`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Me.MaximizedBounds = Screen.FromHandle(Me.Handle).WorkingArea
```

Comment: Thanks @MatSnow. I'm not the OP but know your comment will come in handy for me in future.

Comment: What if I want it to be of a particular size on form_maximize event? @MatSnow

Comment: What if I want it to be of a particular size on form_maximize event? @MatSnow